# How to make Vancouver style that has space after number and not indent second line?

Tags: biblatex, natbib

How do I format the references like this style?

[image: example style]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us please a short compilable tex code showing how you build your bibliography? Do not forget to add one or two bib entries too. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: What document class are you using? (Also, this is not proper Vancouver style, which requires the subsequent lines to line up.)